# Spring Data Rest & projections

Tags: spring, projection, spring-data-rest

I want to return only a subset of my data to the client. i.e. use a projection. Some docs imply that a query can return a projection but I get the error shown below. If I change the query to return the supplier entity it all works fine.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!`

The query:

`Page<SupplierLookupProjection> 
findByApSupplierCodeContainsIgnoreCaseOrAdminAddressContainsIgnoreCaseOrderByApSupplierCodeAsc(Pageable pageable, @Param("code") String code, @Param("description") String description);`

The repository:

`public interface SupplierRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Supplier, Long>`

Comment: Is `SupplierLookupProjection` an interface that defines the projection?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at how `SupplierLookupProjection`  is implemented, I believe you might have missed defining `SupplierLookupProjection` as projection interface.

If so, do define `SupplierLookupProjection` as projection interface with the `getters` for the fields the you are interested in.

For ex: hypothetically, if you want only `name` and `location` field of `Supplier` the you can define projection interface with only those getters as below:

```
interface SupplierLookupProjection {
    String getName();
    String getLocation();
}
```

You can refer to [Spring Data JPA projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) for more examples.

Comment: I have done all of that and also used the @Projection annotation

Comment: @Projection(name = "SupplierLookup", types = { Supplier.class })
public interface SupplierLookupProjection {

 // SpEL expressions refer to the real property on the entity
 // but have the downside of doing select * from table in the query rather than just selecting the columns that are required
 @Value("#{target.apSupplierCode}")
 String getCode();

 @Value("#{target.adminAddress}")
 String getDisplayField();

 // String getAdminAddress();
 Long getId();

}